# How to create a GUI using batch or other programming languages

Tags: batch-file, mouse

How can I create a GUI program using batch programming. How can I program the mouse? I tried installing mouse.com file and the mouse worked in DOS. How to make such stuff using just batch or other programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using visual studio or other Windows GUI tool,

i'm not sure if this can be done from batch file directly..  :/

there seems to be no command for GUI in batch script..

so, in other words, Batch file cannot create GUI..

Maybe i'm wrong..

Comment: You can call powershell from a bat file which is totally capable of working with GUI but it's a pain in the a**.

Answer (score 1):

Using batch is totaly wrong for such tasks. You should take a look at AutoIt (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). It's an easy to learn script language that can be compiled to exe files and allows you to work with GUI, simulate mouse and keyboard actions etc.